# adobe flash image color inconsistency

Tags: flash

After much experimenting I can't seem to solve this issue - 
imported images get tinted in an undesirable/inconsistent way when imported and 
published within flash.

images look consistent traveling between photoshop / image preview / illustrator / etc.

they also look fine on co-workers versions of flash -

the image in cs6 ( see the inconsistency between the library and the stage ) ... 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssjhvrjad9udc27/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-06%20at%205.18.13%20PM.png

and how it should appear ( flash cc ) ... 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8s1zt7d0mhzt5d0/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-06%20at%205.19.32%20PM.png

I need to use cs6 or earlier since I am working in as2 ... 
this is driving me crazy and not sure what to do to solve this -

thanks in advance for any suggestions -